# Manually added keychain password not showing on Mac

Tags: macos, safari, password, keychain

I have a website I previously logged into using iCloud Keychain that has changed its domain/URL. I can still log in by using "other passwords" and finding the old domain, however this isn't ideal. I would prefer to have the keychain working as intended.

So, I added the new domain login manually to my Keychain on my MacBook. However, this still doesn't seem to be working. When I navigate to the login page in Safari it doesn't automatically fill in the fields, and I still have to find the login details in "other passwords"

I know I got the address correct when setting up the new keychain item because I copied and pasted the full URL to the form. I also quit and restarted Safari to see if that would make a difference, but it didn't. Is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 2):

Try deleting the password. Then try loging in with your normal username and password. Safari should ask you if you want to save the password to Keychain.

In this way macOS will save the website with the correct URL and details.